# Suppose that the sets $A_{1},A_{2} \subset \mathbb{R}^n $ are connected and that they are not disjoint. Prove that $A_{1} \cup A_{2}$ is connected.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, connectedness, path-connected

> Suppose that the sets $A_{1},A_{2} \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ are connected and that they are not disjoint. Prove that $A_{1} \cup A_{2}$ is connected.

The section including this question contains this theorem:

[image]

And the following definition:

A is disconnected if there exists open sets B,C such that $A\cap B$ and $A \cap C$ are nonempty, disjoint sets and $A \subset B\cup C.$ A is connected if it is not disconnected.

but I do not know how to use this information to prove the required, could anyone help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose by contradiction that $A_1 \cup A_2 \subset C\cup D$ where $C,D$ are open and $C\cap (A_1 \cup A_2) \ne \emptyset,D\cap (A_1 \cup A_2) \ne \emptyset$ and $(C\cap D) \cap (A_1 \cup A_2) = \emptyset$.

As $A_1,A_2$ are connected each are either in $C$ or $D$ , if ,say , both in $C$ then their union $A_1\cup A_2$ would also be in $C$ and then $D\cap (A_1 \cup A_2)= \emptyset$ a contradiction. 
So we have that W.L.O.G $A_1 \subset C$ and $A_2 \subset D$ but then $A_1\cap A_2 =\emptyset$ , a contradiction.

Note that we didn't use the fact that we are in $\Bbb R^n$ which means we proved that any union of connected sets with nonempty intersection is connected.

Comment: are you proving by contradiction using the definition of disconnectedness?

Comment: Yes, assuming $A_1\cup A_2$ is not connected we get those $C,D$

Comment: very nice proof :)

Comment: @hopefully thanks :) note that i didn't use the fact that the space is $\Bbb R^n$

Comment: but disconnectedness say that $A_{1} \cup A_{2} \subset C \cup D$ not equal

Comment: I wrote open *in* $A_1\cup A_2$

Comment: So does it matter not using that the space is $\mathbb{R^n}$?

Comment: it don't, it just showing you that any union of connected sets that are not disjoint is connected